# What ways are there to do an individual hover on elements that were iterated in React?

Tags: reactjs, json, iteration, hover

I'm rendering elements with the map function in react, the problem is that when hovering, the effect is applied to all the elements and what I'm looking for is an individual effect for each card.

This is my code:

```
const Card = () => {

    const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(false);

    const handleMouseOver = () => {
        setIsHovering(true);
    };

    const handleMouseOut = () => {
        setIsHovering(false);
    };

    return (
        <>
            {productsList.map((product) => (
            <div key={product.id}>
                <div className="relative mb-4" onMouseOver={handleMouseOver} onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}>
                    <img src={product.img} alt="product" className="w-fit h-fit jshover cursor-pointer" />
                    {isHovering ? <CardOptions /> : ""}
                </div>
                <div className="flex justify-center flex-col px-3">
                    <h3 className="captialize font-sans font-bold text-black mb-3">Adicolor Classics Joggers</h3>
                    <div className="flex justify-between ">
                        <span className="capitalize font-normal font-sans text-[#777777]">Dress</span>
                        <span className="font-sans font-bold">$63.85</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}
```

I am iterating an external array of objects with the information of each card.

[As seen in the image, I hover my mouse over a card and the "shop now" box appears on all cards.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGWCH.png)

What would be the best way to do it?

Without iteration of course it worked, but then using React is pointless.

Edit: [SOLVED] The state has to have the index of the iteration of the function. So the conditional rendering has to be conditioned on the index and not on a boolean value.

Like this:

```
const Card = () => {

const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(-1);
const handleMouseOver = (item) => {
    setIsHovering(item);
};

const handleMouseOut = () => {
    setIsHovering(-1);
};


return (
    <>
        {productsList.map((product, index) => (
            <div key={product.id}>
                <div className="relative mb-4" onMouseOver={() => {
                    handleMouseOver(index);
                }} onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}>
                    <img src={product.img} alt="product" className="w-fit h-fit jshover cursor-pointer" />
                    {isHovering === index ? <CardOptions /> : ""}
                </div>
                <div className="flex justify-center flex-col px-3">
                    <h3 className="captialize font-sans font-bold text-black mb-3">{product.title}</h3>
                    <div className="flex justify-between ">
                        <span className="capitalize font-normal font-sans text-[#777777]">{product.category}</span>
                        <span className="font-sans font-bold">{product.price}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
    </>
)
```